# file not found in upload using backbone, xhr and node js

Tags: jquery, node.js, backbone.js, file-upload, xmlhttprequest

I am a beginner in backbone so excuse my stupidity, I am trying to upload a file by adding a function in Backbone.editors: in my views that is what i wrote:

```
Backbone.Form.editors.Filepicker = Backbone.Form.editors.Base.extend(_.extend(
validatorExt, disablingExt, autoActionExt, {
  className: 'form-data',
  events: {
    'change input[type=file]': 'uploadFile' 
  },
  initialize: function (options) {
      Backbone.Form.editors.Base.prototype.initialize.call(this,options);
      this.$uploadInput = $(
      '<input type="file" multiple="multiple" id="' + this.key +
      '" name="' + this.key + '"  multiple/>');
      this.$loader = $(
      '<p class="upload-status"><span class="loader"></span> Uploading&hellip;</p>'
    );
      this.$error = $('<p class="upload-error error">Error</p>');
      this.$list = $('<ul class="file-list">');
  },
  uploadFile: function () {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = 'upload/';
    this.onProgress(0, 'Upload started.');
 var files = document.getElementById(this.key)
      .files;
    var file = files[0];
  xhr.addEventListener('progress', function (e) {
      var done = e.position || e.loaded,
        total = e.totalSize || e.total;
      console.log('xhr progress: ' + (Math.floor(done / total *
        1000) / 10) + '%');
    }, false);
    if (xhr.upload) {
      xhr.upload.onprogress = function (e) {
        var done = e.position || e.loaded,
          total = e.totalSize || e.total;
        console.log('xhr.upload progress: ' + done + ' / ' +
          total + ' = ' + (Math.floor(done / total * 1000) /
            10) + '%');
      };
    }
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function (e) {
      if (4 === this.readyState) {
        console.log(['xhr upload complete', e]);
      }
    };
 xhr.open('POST', url, true);
    console.log(xhr);
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append(this.key, file, file.name);
     xhr.send(formData);
  }));
```

in my server side :

```
app.post('/upload/', multer({dest: './tmp/my-uploads'}).array(), uploadFile);
function uploadFile(req, res) {
 console.log(req.body.file);
  console.log(req.file);
  res.status(204).end();
 }
```

this scripts creates the upload folder, but the file isn't transfered in the server side! while i can read the name and the size of the doc, and for the console.log both are undefined! 
I think the real problem, the web service '/upload/ is not sending the binary data. what should i do?

It is resolved! I had to activate the upload service in my server with this line of code :

```
   app.use(express.bodyParser({
      keepExtensions: true,
      uploadDir: '/uploads'
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

By using just `.array()` you're only saving non-file multipart fields. Since it seems like you're uploading a file, you'd want something like:

```
var upload = multer({dest: './tmp/my-uploads'});
app.post('/upload/', upload.single('foo'), function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body.file);
  console.log(req.file);
  res.status(204).end();
});
```

where `'foo'` is the `name` attribute associated with the file input field (`this.key` in your case).

Comment: always the same problem, i don't find the binary code of the file to send it to the server

Comment: Did you check the request in your browser's web dev tools to make sure the file field is indeed being sent (and what field name is being used)?

Comment: yes, in the views.js, cosole.log(file) show the file, its name, size... and FileReader(file) shows the content of the file